# Auto-play and keep omxplayer-pi running on Ubuntu Core 18

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I got Ubuntu Core 18 running on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. I want the computer to boot and automatically play a video file to HDMI output and loop.

I can log in via SSH and run `omxplayer-pi test.mp4` and it plays a video on a TV connected via HDMI.

How do I automate this so that it runs on boot?

Once I get the basic automation in place, I'll probably want to write a script to keep trying to play the video if, for example, the `omxplayer-pi` process dies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bit of work on Ubuntu Core. It was for me, anyway--I had to learn the ins and outs of building, installing, and using snaps. There are documentation and examples available and it worked as advertised.

After getting a [hot tip](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-running-other-snap-cant-read-files-in-home-dir/9272/2?u=meonkeys) I hacked on on https://github.com/ogra1/iptv-player-snap. My fork is [here](https://github.com/meonkeys/iptv-player-snap). It will automatically loop a video on boot on an ubuntu core raspberry pi. No X server or window manager required!

Note: there's an [easy alternative video looper that runs on raspbian](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-video-looper/).